# AJAX not receiving response from servlet

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, servlets

I have an AJAX making a POST to a servlet. Servlet does some computation and returns a response. AJAX success function reads the response and does certain things.

AJAX CALL

```
$.ajax( {
     type: "POST",
     url: "/bin/path/to/Servlet",
     data: $(this).serialize(),
     dataType: "html",
     success: function(responseValue) {
         if(responseValue == '200') {
              // Do something
          }else {
              console.log("it is not 200");
          }
     },
     error: trialForm.trialError
     }).done(function(status) {
             $(trialForm.submitButton).show();
             $(trialForm.loader).hide();
     });
}
```

SERVLET

```
protected void doPost(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) {
     response.setContentType("text/html");    

     URL url = new URL("www.apriurl.com");
     HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
     conn.setDoOutput(true);
     conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
     conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
     conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization","XXXXZZZZ " + strSig);
     conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
     conn.setRequestProperty("ZZZZZ",clientID);

     OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
     os.write(inputParameters.getBytes());
     os.flush(); 

     System.out.println(conn.getResponseCode());
     response.getWriter().write(conn.getResponseCode());
}
```

- responseValue is a variable used in teh java class.
- It has the right value. I see the value being print in log file after sys out executed
- The response is just a garbled question mark (?). I console logged it. I am guessing it has to do something with the data type. I tried a few other types but couldn;t figure out. Any help is appreicated.

Comment: You question is not very clear.  For a start it does not appear that you are adding `responseValue` to your `response` in the servlet, and also it does not seem that you are retrieving and using `responseValue` in your JS

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to remove unnecessary code from the post. Clearly, I did not do a good job at it. Basically, Servelt interacts with a 3rd party api, and whatever resposne it gets from that 3rd part, it passes onto AJAX. I resposne I get from 3rd party is fine, I can log it but haven't been able to pass it on to AJAX

Comment: Yes, I tried `response.getWriter().write("test");` instead the ajax callback function gets the value instead of garbled text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is doing a `write (int)` rather than a `write (String)`
so if you do `write(200)` it is sending the ascii value of 200

try sending `200` as a String

as

```
response.getWriter().write(String.valueOf (conn.getResponseCode()));
```

see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#write(int)

> public void write(int c)
>
> Writes a single character.

Comment: Thanks! I did `response.getWriter().write(String.valueOf(conn.getResponseCode()));` and that works

Comment: Absolutely! I was just too busy gloating over working code.  Thank you very much!